# What is the 'SearchableActivity.JARGON' boolean variable in Android?

Tags: android, android-search, android-searchmanager

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
     Bundle appData = new Bundle();
     appData.putBoolean(SearchableActivity.JARGON, true);
     startSearch(null, false, appData, false);
     return true;
 }
```

I have taken this [snippet form this developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).

The question is that is `SearchableActivity.JARGON` just an identifier/name just like any other name (like `'myBoolean'` or `'bool'` etc.)? Or is it some special key in Android?

I couldn't find any information specific about `SearchableActivity.JARGON` from my Google search.

Comment: This confuzed me too. Pretty sure it's just example of how you can pass smth with Bundle, since there is no such a class in sdk like SearchableActivity.